Installing Stata on Ubuntu 24.04 - required libraries no longer existing
After installing Stata 18 on my fresh LTS Ubuntu I couldn't run it:
./stata: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Turns out that package is outdated, removed by Debian (and Ubuntu follows that).
However, one can manually download that package. Yet, it has more dependencies:
$ sudo dpkg -i libncurses5_6.2-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 403219 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libncurses5_6.2-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libncurses5:i386 (6.2-0ubuntu2.1) over (6.2-0ubuntu2.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libncurses5:i386:
 libncurses5:i386 depends on libtinfo5 (= 6.2-0ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package libtinfo5:i386 is not configured yet.
 libncurses5:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.7); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.

One step back further, libc6 (also manually downloaded) -- this gives me
$ sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.15_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 403219 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.15_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:i386 (2.31-0ubuntu9.15) over (2.31-0ubuntu9.15) ...
dpkg: error processing package libc6:i386 (--install):
 package libc6:i386 2.31-0ubuntu9.15 cannot be configured because libc6:amd64 is at a different version (2.39-0ubuntu8.1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:i386

At this point I'm reaching the end of my understanding.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Surely there must be a more convenient way of installing a major software like Stata18 on the current LTS version of Ubuntu
If I'm barking up the right tree: how do I go about installing these libraries?


You're doing some things very wrong, let me explain. Your first mistake is here:
sudo dpkg -i libncurses5_6.2-0ubuntu2.1_i386.deb 

You're trying to install the i386 (32-bit) version of this package, when Ubuntu (and most other Linux systems) now only run 64-bit (AMD64).
So first, clean up the mess of your installed i386 packages by removing everything you tried (there are many existing Q&A's about removing broken packages).
The correct package for Ubuntu 24.04 would probably be libncurses6, which is installed with:
sudo apt install libncurses6

A couple of lessons to be learnt:

Never install i386 packages (just EVER, unless you really know what you're doing)
Don't install manually downloaded packages with dpkg - instead install official packages from repositories using apt

You might have to create the correct symlink yourself (from ncurses5 to ncurses6), as mentioned here. ncurses libraries are inside /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ on Ubuntu, like this:
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6.4 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5


"instead install official packages from repositories using"- ncurses 5 and 6 are not compatible. If the software you're using wants 5, and Ubtuntu 24 decided to not make it available (thanks Ubuntu), you don't have any other option.

I'm surprised this answer was accepted. If your software needs ncurses5, installing ncurses6 is does not solve anything.
Also, ncurses5 indeed depends on the i386 version of libtinfo5, so this step was correct.
